# Using both cached and non-cached JSON from an Ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, caching

I have two JSON sources: getCachedJSON.php and getNotCachedJSON.php.  As suggested by the names, the client should cache the results from the first but not the second.  Both of these files will issue the appropriate headers to tell the client to cache or not cache the data.

How is this best accomplished?

I came up with the following, but don't know if this is how it should be done.  And if it is the right way, should the cached JSON be first requested and then the non-cached JSON, or the other way around?

```
$.ajax({
    //cache: true,
    url: "getCachedJSON.php",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(cachedJSON) {
        $.ajax({
            //cache: false,
            url: "getNotCachedJSON.php",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(notCachedJSON) {
                var allJSON = $.extend({}, cachedJSON, notCachedJSON);
                console.log(allJSON);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: By caching you meant that you do not want to make request to server?

Comment: @KamenStoykov  If the client has the data provided by getNotCachedJSON.php, then I do not wish it to make another request to the server.

Comment: php or htaccess/webserver would be the place to handle this.

Comment: Having two different URLs for the same data seems a little bit strange...I would expect most caching control to come from the server, not the client, so maybe you could try to describe what your intent is for this?

Comment: @KevinB  I could certainly use the server to control caching (and in fact edited the original post to show it this way), however, the question remains how to integrate both cached and non-cached results.

Comment: @Katana314  I agree that caching control should come from the server, and edited the original post to show it this way.  My intent is when both results which could be cached and other results which cannot be cached are needed, how can I leverage the client to allow caching.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by integrating cached and non-cached results? creating an array that is the combined of the two? that has nothing to do with caching.. or even ajax.

Comment: @KevinB  Maybe "integrating" was not the right word.  I have JavaScript which needs data provided by the server, and some of that data could be cached but some of it could not be.

Comment: *"I came up with the following, but don't know if this is how it should be done"* Well, **does it work**?

Comment: @KevinB  I haven't tested it, yet I am confident it will work.  But as Katana314 indicated, it "seems a little bit strange"...

Comment: The only strange part is needing a separate url for the cached data. There's no reason to have that, your php should return cache control headers by default, and if the client wants a non-cached version it can append a cachebuster to the url.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91667/discussion-between-kevin-b-and-user1032531).

Answer (score 1):

Browser manages caching for you. Each time when you're making GET request the browser check if it has this resources in its cache. If it has it then request is not made. To tell browser how to control caching you have to use http headers like cache-control and max-age (try to google for details). You have to set these headers when browsers access you server. You can use chrome's dev tools (network) to inspect if there is any requests made. There you will see if resource is obtained from cache or from request.

If you want event better cache control I recommend you to use service workers or browser sql databases.

Hope I understood your question right.

Comment: Thanks Kamen,  The part I am confused about is having two different sources. where only half of the data is allowed to be cached.  Instead of using `cache: false` for the non-cached data, I could instead using HTTP headers as you indicated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a server request and cache it on the client side, you can make use of the browser's local storage.

You could do something along the lines of this:

```
var allData = cached(nonCached);

function cached(callback){
    var cachedData = localStorage.getItem('cached');
    // if locally stored data is found, pass it to the callback
    if(cachedData){
        callback(JSON.parse(cachedData));
    } else {
        // Else get it from php script, store it, and pass to callback
        $.ajax({
            url: "getNotCachedJSON.php",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(cachedData) {
                var key = 'cached';
                localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(cachedData));  
                callback(cachedData);
            }
        });
    }
}


function nonCached(cachedData){
    $.ajax({
        url: "getNotCachedJSON.php",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(nonCachedData) {
            return $.extend({}, cachedData, nonCachedData);
        }
     });
}
```